# Windows 10 works beautifully plugged in, but on battery internet slow & many pages don't load

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 works beautifully for our needs when the laptop is plugged in to power source- just did the upgrade from 8.1 two days ago.

But when working on battery power, the internet - tried Firefox and Chrome - is extremely slow, with many pages not loading at all: `Can't find page...server error` type messages.

Plugged back in to the power source, it works normally again. This issue was not present with Windows 8 or 8.1.

Comment: Did you check in the control pannel power settings, in the "advanced" settings modern windows has had a wireless power item there in existance.  in win7 one could set the wireless to "maximum power", on a laptop you would want to make sure it was also set there when on battery (as needed)

Comment: Yes, I set the wireless adapter to "maximum power" when on battery. I've checked again and the problem persists, and the wireless adapter setting is still "maximum power."

Comment: First, how old is the computer, 2nd; did you make any changes to settings to the adapter its self by setting it to **half duplex**, 3rd; have you changed and or replaced the WiFi adapter at anytime